# Python error while scraping forum with dynamic url for a specific word wtih BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm fairly new to Python and I'm building a small app to scrape a Spanish forum for a specific word so I can try and get news about Nintendo Switch stock (quite hard to come by) and also for training/entertainment. I intend to have it check every 15 minutes or so and then sending updates to a Telegram Bot, but for now I'm struggling with getting the results from the whole thread.

Here's a sample:

```
import requests

#TODO: Have the get method loop through every iteration of a forum page: s10, s20, s30...

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.elotrolado.net/hilo_disponibilidad-nintendo-switch-seguimiento-de-pedidos_2210603_s"

for i in range(10,10000,10):
    stringer = str(i)
    page = requests.get(url%(stringer,)).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
    results = soup.find_all(lambda tag: "stock" in tag.string if tag.string else False)
    scraped_paragraphs = map(lambda element: element.string, results)
    print(scraped_paragraphs)
```

When I run this I get `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

Each new page of the forum adds 10 at the end of the URL, like so:

```
First page: https://www.elotrolado.net/hilo_disponibilidad-nintendo-switch-seguimiento-de-pedidos_2210603

Second page: https://www.elotrolado.net/hilo_disponibilidad-nintendo-switch-seguimiento-de-pedidos_2210603_s10

Third page: https://www.elotrolado.net/hilo_disponibilidad-nintendo-switch-seguimiento-de-pedidos_2210603_s20

etc...
```

Not sure what I'm missing here, I've managed to scrape a single page, but this loop is resisting me!

Answer (score 0):

I thought to try looking for a string that I know exists in one of the pages in the series: 'amazon'. I see two minor, possible flaws in the code.

One is that it would fail to identify variations in case (such as 'Amazon', 'AMAZON', etc). The other is that `map` yields an iterator.

```
>>> import requests
>>> page = requests.get('https://www.elotrolado.net/hilo_disponibilidad-nintendo-switch-seguimiento-de-pedidos_2210603_s20').content
>>> import bs4
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
>>> results = soup.find_all(lambda tag: 'amazon' in tag.string.lower() if tag.string else False)
>>> len(results)
3
>>> list(map(lambda elem: elem.string, results))
[' A las 10:30 abre la preventa Amazon España!!! ', ' Me llego email de Amazon, la ponen a las 10:30am ', ' El enlace de amazon de la neón lo tenéis? gracias. ']
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your expected output is, but please try this:

`for i in range(10, 10000, 10):
    stringer = int(i)
    page = requests.get(url + '%d' % stringer)
    print(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
    results = soup.find_all(lambda tag: "stock" in tag.string if tag.string else False)
    scraped_paragraphs = list(map(lambda element: element.string, results))
    print(scraped_paragraphs)`